# Python menu command (Tkinter.Menu's add_command) to resize root window 'activated' prematurely

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I'm trying to add a menu command to resize the root window (increase 2X in this example). However, the resize_window() functions seems to be activated right away when the program is run, and not on the selection of the View->Resize 2X menu command.

With the example below, I'm expecting is that when the program is run, the window launches initially with a size of 400x300, and upon choosing the Resize-2X menu, the main window resizes to 800x600.

I'm new to Tkinter and am sure something in my code is not right. Could someone help?

I'm using Anaconda (python 2.7)

> > sys.version
> >     '2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

```
import Tkinter

launchWidth = 400
launchHeight = 300
launchOffsetX = 100
launchOffsetY = 100

###### 2 Initialize Main Window
root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("My Email Program")
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(launchWidth,launchHeight,launchOffsetX,launchOffsetY))

def resize_window(master,factor):
    newWidth = int(factor * launchWidth)
    newHeight= int(factor * launchHeight)
    master.geometry("%dx%d"%(newWidth,newHeight))

###### Building Menu
menuBar = Tkinter.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menuBar)
menuView = Tkinter.Menu(menuBar,tearoff=0)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="View",menu=menuView)
menuView.add_command(label="Resize 2.0X",command=resize_window(root,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that by providing arguments you are in fact calling the function when you create the menu entry.
you would need to use a lambda in this situation, change this:

```
menuView.add_command(label="Resize 2.0X",command=resize_window(root,2))
```

to this:

```
menuView.add_command(label="Resize 2.0X",command=lambda:resize_window(root,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function as soon as you add it to the menu.

```
menuView.add_command(label="Resize 2.0X",command=resize_window(root,2))
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

You have to pass in a command that can be called to produce the desired result. This is a common use case for `lambda` functions, which allow you to define an inline anonymous function:

```
menuView.add_command(label="Resize 2.0X",command=lambda: resize_window(root,2))
```

Now you've sent in a function, which can be called at runtime with the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3.
When the command calls a non-root-related function (eg, tkMessageBox.showinfo), they don't get activated prematurely.
How is root different in this sense?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the root object. If you pass in a reference to a function, it'll work like it should. If you pass in a called function (like `print()` instead of `print`), it'll call it immediately, and then, when you try to use that menu command, it'll try to call the value returned by the earlier call (e.g. it'll try to do `None()` if you passed in `print()`).